# Using Ubuntu 12.04 with Chrome Stable/Beta and watching youtube gives be a black bar at the top

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

As the picture [image: Ubuntu with chrome with the error]

As you can see there's a black bar, is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried after disabling all extensions? I checked that same page (www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RY-_nYbS-E) and didn't see that black bar. Also, is it just on this page or on all YouTube pages?

Comment: @vasa1 I disabled all extension and plugins except Flash. This is on the Youtube page itself. Even in fullscreen it seem to be offsetting from the top with some amount.

Comment: What about `about:flags`? Have you enabled anything there or forced hardware acceleration?

Comment: @vasa1 Tried forced and disabled. Other than that I haven't enable anything else.

Comment: One more thing ... You should be having **two** Flash plug-ins, '/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so` and `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`. Try with just one enabled at a time.

Comment: @vasa1 The weird thing is I only have "1" Flash plugin. I think something fishy is going on now, because everywhere I read it says there's 2-3 flash plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a solution, to people with this problem I think the chrome flash plugin is bugged and if you only have one flash to choose from in "chrome://plugins" you will need to install the external library of ubuntu. Install that and there should be an option in chrome. Disable the one with "/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so"